# How could you access the GitHub API in Swift?

Tags: swift, github-api

I'd like to make an update detection system in my macOS SwiftUI app by pulling the latest release from GitHub via the API and then comparing the tag. How would I go about accessing the API from Swift? I've tried using the methods from [here, medium.com](https://medium.com/swlh/fetch-data-from-apis-in-swiftui-74b4b50f20e9), [here, swifttom.com](https://swifttom.com/2021/01/11/how-to-fetch-json-data-from-apis-in-swiftui/) and [here, steveclarkapps.com](https://www.steveclarkapps.com/rest-basics/) but none of them accomplish what I'm trying to do.

For the first method, the code functions with the provided example API, but doesn't work with the GitHub API and it returns this error instead:

`Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Method 2 suffers the same issue.

I couldn't even get enough of method 3's code working to try it.

Here's my adapted code based off of the medium.com method:

`Model.swift`

```swift
import Foundation

struct TaskEntry: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let tag_name: String
    let name: String
}
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [TaskEntry]()
        
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases/latest") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                /*if*/ let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data) /*{*/
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = response
                    }
                    return
                /*}*/
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Commented out code and variable names that seem irrelevant are just leftovers.

**OS:** macOS Big Sur 11.6
**Xcode version:** 13.0

Comment: You have a dictionary, not an array, duhhh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open this in your browser:

https://api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases/latest

You will notice it is not an array but an object. You should be decoding an object like this:

```swift
JSONDecoder().decode(TaskEntry.self, from: data)
```

Edit:

This requires you to change your view. Notice this is no longer a `List` because you are no longer fetching an array but a single item:

```swift
struct TaskEntry: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let tagName: String
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entry: TaskEntry? = nil
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let entry = entry {
                Text("\(entry.id)")
                Text(entry.name)
                Text(entry.tagName)
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases/latest") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                // TODO: Handle data task error
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                // TODO: Handle this
                return
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            
            do {
                let response = try decoder.decode(TaskEntry.self, from: data)
                
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.entry = response
                    }
            } catch {
                // TODO: Handle decoding error
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

NOTICE: I did some other improvements as well

1. Use JSONDecoder to convert from snake case to camel case
2. Added do catch block so your app doesn't crash
3. Check for errors before decoding
4. Added loading indicator (had to put something in the else)

However,

As our discussion you are probably calling the wrong endpoint. That endpoint is not returning an array but a single object, you can tell this because the JSON response begins with `{` rather than `[`

I've adjusted my answer to change the endpoint I believe you should be calling:

```swift
struct TaskEntry: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let tagName: String
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results: [TaskEntry]? = nil
            
    var body: some View {
        if let results = results {
            List(results, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        } else {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ProgressView()
                    .onAppear(perform: loadData)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                // TODO: Handle data task error
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                // TODO: Handle this
                return
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            
            do {
                let response = try decoder.decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data)
                
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = response
                    }
            } catch {
                // TODO: Handle decoding error
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately breaks the rest of the code that uses the TaskEntry struct. Should I be setting up TaskEntry differently? (Or just set change the way I handle in it in my `ContentView.swift`?)

Comment: Well thats what the endpoint you are using returns so you should be updating your ContentView. But perhaps you're using the wrong endpoint? It's odd that you were expecting an array but got a single object. Perhaps this is the endpoint you're supposed to be using: https://api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases. If you click on that link, you will notice its an array of objects

Comment: I mean that changing `JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data)` to `JSONDecoder().decode(TaskEntry.self, from: data)` like you suggested broke all of the rest of the code that interacts with `TaskEntry`. The best example is the `self.results = response` line right below it which now gives the error `Cannot assign value of type 'TaskEntry' to type 'TaskEntry.Type'`. I've tried my best to adjust the code that no longer works based on Xcode's suggestions but it only seems to have made things worse.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. you changed the type from [TaskEntry] to TaskEntry (an array to a single object) of course you would need to adjust your code if you do that. But I think you were using the wrong endpoint the whole time. Undo your changes and change the url to `api.github.com/repos/NCX-Programming/RNGTool/releases`

Comment: I simply looked at the data the endpoint was providing and noticed it wasn't returning an array but a single object. I think you need to take a step back because I don't think you fully  understand `JSON` objects and arrays. Or Swift arrays and objects. Or what JSONDecoder does and how it works. Maybe play around with it on playgrounds first

Comment: Yeah I think you're right about all of that. I'll try and learn how all of that works and then come back to this. In the meantime I'm marking your answer as correct since I'm assuming it would do what I want, if I knew what I was doing.

Comment: I’ll post a fuller answer to your problem shortly. One that compiles and runs. So you can see the difference between the array and object. That should clarify the difference