# display Github data using "Github API" (SwiftUI)

Tags: github, swiftui, github-api

**task** to be done: Make your github data appear on the ContentView screen using the Github API.

```
struct TaskEntry: Codable  {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}
```

```
    @State var results = [TaskEntry]()
    
    func loadData() {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") else {
                print("Invalid URL")
                return
            }
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.results = response
                        }
                        return
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

the above solution did not help in performing this task

[i didn't understand how to use these docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users#get-a-user)

Thank you for attention.
help those who know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this approach to display some info retrieved from github.

You need to have a model for your info, here I called it `Repository`.
You then need to fetch the info from the github server using the appropriate url as shown in `loadData`. Finally you need to display the info in your View, as shown in `ContentView`.

```
struct Repository: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, fullName: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [Repository]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(results) { repo in
                Text(repo.name)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/workingdog/repos") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    self.results = try JSONDecoder().decode([Repository].self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

Note, to retrieve your github repo info, replace `workingdog` in the url with your github name.

PS: did you read the answer to your previous question at: [get the Field datas according to the Ids from the Collection in the Firestore/SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082620/get-the-field-datas-according-to-the-ids-from-the-collection-in-the-firestore-sw)

did the answer not work for you?

Comment: yes of course I read, I understood what I read today :) [here](https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-http-request) (ps: linking files, fetching data from the server, api I had a *hard time* understanding things like that)  but thank you so much for your attention..! @workingdog

Comment: [this](https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-http-request) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624063/how-could-you-access-the-github-api-in-swift)  can each of these **two links** be adapted as an answer to this question? did not look like me ;( @workingdog.  if you try for me, *please*

Comment: the code in my answer, does the same as the links you show. Does the code in my answer not work for you?

Comment: What if I want to take a picture and put it in my view? ```import SDWebImageSwiftUI```  ```WebImage(url: URL(string: user.avatar_url))```   when I did so I **received** the following message: *The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.* @workingdog

Comment: it is best to ask a new question regarding your issue with `WebImage(url: URL(string: user.avatar_url))`. Include the code you are using and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

of course, I respect the answers given. this is my result(inspired by the answers):

[image]

if this result is of interest to you: [here](https://github.com/Sanjar-As?tab=repositories#:%7E:text=get%2Dmy%2DgitHub%2Ddata_ui)